# Pull out a substring with a string of indeterminate length

Tags: sql-server, substring

I am trying to update a table I have with the windows version of a SQL Server using `@@VERSION`. When I run `SELECT @@VERSION` I get

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64) 
May 14 2014 18:34:29 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

AND in this case I want "Windows NT 6.3" (14 characters long) that will never change I always want the 14 characters "Windows NT ***(some version)***".

Sometime when I query some servers the "(Hypervisor)" Isn't there or the parentheses and text after those 14 characters is different. I want to automate this and I need to find a way to pull out just "Windows NT ***(some version)***".

Comment: Look for "Windows NT" and then look for the ")" immediately following that. `charindex()` and `substring()`

Comment: I think I misread which part you want. But still easy if spaces are reliable delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

`charindex()` lets you find the location of substrings within a string. It also let's you specify a third argument to begin the search in the middle of the string which allows us to find a match relative to another location. We'll use that function several times.

We need to know the start of our desired string and the end of it. So we anchor our search to the string `"Windows NT "` which is 11 characters long. Then we want to find the next space character immediately following that match. It's necessary to add 11 to that value so it doesn't find the space characters inside the anchoring match (before and after the "NT".)

```
charindex('Windows NT ', @@version) /* start of match */
charindex(' ', @@version, charindex('Windows NT ', @@version) + 11) /* end of match */
```

Those two expressions identify the string offset but `substring()` needs to know the *length* to extract which means it needs to know the difference between the offsets. Since we don't want the final space character in the return value there's no need to add one to include it.

```
substring(
    @@version,
    charindex('Windows NT ', @@version),
    charindex(' ', @@version, charindex('Windows NT ', @@version) + 11)
        - charindex('Windows NT ', @@version)
)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks this fixes my problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you know it will always be Windows, you can use that fact to search where "on Windows" is in that string since it should always only ever be present once. Once you know the starting position you can use substring and adjust the parameters such that the string "on " is removed and then just pull your 14 characters.
IE:
    declare @str varchar(500) = 'Microsoft SQL Server xxx (SPy) - 10.0.5500.0
    (X64) 
    Sep 21 2011 22:45:45 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack
    1) (VM)
    '
    select @str
    select SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX('on Windows', @str,1) + 3 ,14)

Comment: It might take a few years for it to become a problem but do you really want to rely on it always being fourteen characters? Windows NT 10.0 or Windows NT 6.31?

Comment: thats true and you can adjust the parameter in the substring from 14 to something more dynamic. Or, just punt and wait until its a problem at which time you can address it then, but thats probably not the best way ;)